# Performance issue on permissions table

Tags: sql, database, database-design, database-schema

I am developing a ECM software, where a group of users have permissions on folders. When the folder tree is bigger it can generate a lots of rows on database, like 30k or more.

The permission table structure is below

group_folder_roles

- id_group
- id_folder
- id_role

The main problem is when I have to load all folders with permissions to build the user folder tree.

There´s a better way to do?

**UPDATE**

i was doing something wrong on my code and did not realized. I don´t know how i didn´t notice that.

Latter i measured the response time correctly and was about 300 milliseconds, and discovered that the problem was a sum of the Entity Framework query, the conversion to JSON and the transport.

I fixed using ADO and simplifying the transport process returning a JSON like this:

```
{
   "folder" : 0,
   "roles"  : '0,1,2,3,4,5,6'
}
```

And to make better i compress the result.

Comment: Can't be answered without more concrete information on what you tables and queries and RDBMS are.

Answer (score 1):

If 30k rows is giving you performance problems you need to see why.  You are probably doing something very wrong.  It is hard to hit performance issues in the dbs I have worked with until you get several hundred thousand rows and it sounds like you are an order of magnitude smaller than that.  Here are a few things you will want to look into:

1. Does your rdbms support recursive queries, either by an Oracle-type `CONNECT BY` approach or with the more standard `WITH RECURSIVE` common table expression?  This would allow for better leverage of indexes and management of results.
2. You may look into whether permissions are best modelled using normalized designs or whether an array of ACLs would perform better.  This depends on the RDBMS
3. Closely tied to #2 above is how indexes work on your specific rdbms.  How much do they help?  What can you do to leverage them a lot more?

Comment: Thank you, i had already solved. And you is right, i had some problems on my code and in my query.